# Testing Promise-chains with Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, bluebird

I've got the following style of function (using bluebird promises under Node.JS):

```
module.exports = {
    somefunc: Promise.method(function somefunc(v) {
        if (v.data === undefined)
            throw new Error("Expecting data");

        v.process_data = "xxx";

        return module.exports.someother1(v)
          .then(module.exports.someother2)
          .then(module.exports.someother3)
          .then(module.exports.someother4)
          .then(module.exports.someother5)
          .then(module.exports.someother6);
    }),
});
```

which I'm trying to test (using mocha, sinon, assert):

```
// our test subject
something = require('../lib/something');

describe('lib: something', function() {
    describe('somefunc', function() {
        it("should return a Error when called without data", function(done) {
            goterror = false;
            otherexception = false;
            something.somefunc({})
            .catch(function(expectedexception) {
                try {
                    assert.equal(expectedexception.message, 'Expecting data');
                } catch (unexpectedexception) {
                    otherexception = unexpectedexception;
                }
                goterror = true;
            })
            .finally(function(){
                if (otherexception)
                    throw otherexception;

                 assert(goterror);
                 done();
            });
        });
});
```

All of which works as such, but feels convoluted for one.

My MAIN problem is testing the Promises-chain (and order) in the function. I've tried several things (faking an object with a then method, which didn't work; mocking it like crazy, etc); but there seems to be something I'm not seeing, and I don't seem to be getting the mocha- or sinon- documentations in this regard.

Anybody got any pointers?

Thanks

count

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mocha supports promises so you could do this

```
describe('lib: something', function() {
    describe('somefunc', function() {
        it("should return a Error when called without data", function() {
            return something.somefunc({})
                .then(assert.fail)
                .catch(function(e) {
                    assert.equal(e.message, "Expecting data");
                });
        });
    });
});
```

This is roughly equivalent to the synchronous code:

```
try {
   something.somefunc({});
   assert.fail();
} catch (e) {
   assert.equal(e.message, "Expecting data");
}
```

Comment: how would I mock someother1-6 in this case, so the actual implementations don't get called?

Comment: hmm. IF the assertion in the catch fails I'm getting a "Possibly unhandled AssertionError", how can I let that bubble up correctly?

Comment: @berlincount are you using a mocha version that supports promises? If yes, are you sure are you `return`ing the promise chain like in the answer

Comment: I am. Using

Promise.onPossiblyUnhandledRejection(function(error){
    throw error;
});

as per docs helps.